# Scrape from an empty class tag (HTML)

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape Directors and Actors from `IMDB` from a single webpage which lists top 50 films of 2018. The issue I have is that I have no idea how to scrape them as the class has no name.

Part of my code which is working fine:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2018&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1')

for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item-content'):
    film_lenght = film_details.find('span', class_='runtime').text
    film_genre = film_details.find('span', class_='genre').text
    public_rating = i.find('div', class_='ratings-bar').strong.text
```

Part of the HTML code that I don't know how to work with:

```
</p>, <p class="">
    Directors:
<a href="/name/nm0751577/">Anthony Russo</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0751648/">Joe Russo</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000375/">Robert Downey Jr.</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm1165110/">Chris Hemsworth</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0749263/">Mark Ruffalo</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0262635/">Chris Evans</a>
</p>
```

I want to be able to pull all Directors and all listed Actors for each film. I want to do that from the single URL as provided in the code.

Comment: what is `film_details` equal to?

Comment: @fozoro film_details = i.find('p', class_='text-muted')

Comment: Please, add a running code, with imports and so on. It is hard to, when trying to help, guess about missing parts of your code. Then, ask about where the code is failing, instead of a user-story "I wanna be able to...". If you can put your code on an online sandbox, even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains`, and specify `Director:` or `Directors:`, to target the blocks for each film; then separate the director(s) by grabbing `a` tags before the `span` tag (by filtering out those after). The actors will be the general `a` tag siblings of the `span` tag. Requires bs4 v 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2018&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('p:contains("Director:"), p:contains("Directors:")'):
    #print(item)
    directors = [d.text for d in item.select('a:not(span ~ a)')]
    actors = [d.text for d in item.select('span ~ a')]
    print(directors, actors)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive this error: in select
    'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: It requires bs4.  4.7.1 I meant to add that

Comment: You should upgrade bs4 anyway as it is more robust and has more functionality like the above.

Comment: Did that fix it for you?

Comment: Thanks. Done it. Almost there - it doesn't pull the director and actors of the very first movie

Comment: I know why - it contains the word 'Directors:' instead of 'Director:'

Comment: Is there anyway add the logic for search of Director or Directors?

Comment: There is :D I updated the code to:     for item in i.select('p:contains("Directors:")') or i.select('p:contains("Director:")'):

Comment: Any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

QHarr's answer was great but later I've noticed that some films do not have Director(s) listed at all; in such cases the code ignored these films. Therefore, I updated QHarr's code and now it takes such scenario into account:

'''

```
for item in soup.select('p:contains("Stars:")'):
    reqs += 1
    if item not in soup.select('p:contains("Director:"), p:contains("Directors:")'):
        actors = [d.text for d in item.select('a:not(span ~ a)')]
        directors = ['none']
    else:
        directors = str([d.text for d in item.select('a:not(span ~ a)')]).strip('[]').replace("'","")
        actors = [d.text for d in item.select('span ~ a')]
```

'''